# Stretch div to full width (if space available)

Tags: css, html, width, css-float

i'm currently working on a tumblr theme, but got stuck on the page navigation.
The html for "Previous" and "Next" Buttons or only rendered, if they are available.
So there is no next button on the first page and no previous button on the last page.
and this is where i want the according single button to stretch to 100% width.
I could do this in javascript but it's not an option at all since the template shall work without javascript too.

the html looks like this:

```
<div id="navigation">
<a href="#" id="prev" style="width:476px; float:left;" class="button_normal"><p>Prev</p></a>
<a href="#" id="next" style="width:476px; float:right;"class="button_normal"><p>Next</p></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button_normal {
text-align: center;
opacity: 0.55;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
background: white;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: 100;
color: #646464;
border: 1px solid #646464;
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#navigation{
clear: both;
width: 100%;
}
```

width of the parent div is 960px, so there shall be a 8px margin between the two buttons.
I tried fixing it with min-width and width: 100% auto; but couldn't really figure out how to make it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use table display styles.

`/* add these properties to your stylesheet */

    #navigation { display:table; }

    .button_normal { display:table-cell; }`

```
// remove the inline styles from your anchors
<div id="navigation">
    <a href="#" id="prev" class="button_normal"><p>Prev</p></a>
    <a href="#" id="next" class="button_normal"><p>Next</p></a>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/unuwuh/2

Comment: The only problem with this style is it isn't supported in IE 7 or IE 6. I'm not sure if Janik Lipke cares though.

Comment: Great, this seems to work. Quite easy but I didn't that property at all. The margin in the middle (8px) still seems to be an Issue for me.

Answer (score 7):

You can do the following:

1. Add a `position:relative` to your parent container
2. Create a new class called "full-width" and in it have

   ```
   position: absolute;
   left:0px;
   right:0px;
   ```
3. Add the class `full-width` to the corresponding button

Comment: Where it says: `position:relative`, it should read `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
.continer {
display: flex;
align-items: stretch;
}
```

and for the child component:

```
.subContiner {
width: 100%;
}
```